# How to add space inside a cell in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, line-spacing

How would I add space inside a cell in Excel?

I'm using MS 2007 as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to fix the size of the cell or use word wrap?

Comment: something like a word wrap? so that the next sentence will go to the next space

Comment: can you use the word wrap in one cell?

Comment: that ↵ doesn't look like a *space* to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want text to appear on multiple lines in a cell, you can format the cell so that text wraps automatically, or you can enter a manual line break.

1. Wrap text automatically

   - Select the cells you want to format.
   - On the Format menu, click Cells, and then click the Alignment tab.
   - Under Text control, select the Wrap text check box, and then click OK.

   Note: Data in the cell will wrap to fit the column width. When you change the column width, data wrapping adjusts automatically.
2. Enter a line break

   - To start a new line of text at a specific point in a cell, click where you want to break the line, and then press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

   Note: If all wrapped text is not visible, it may be because the row is set to a specific height. To allow the row to adjust automatically and show all wrapped text, point to Row on the Format menu, and then click AutoFit.

Source: [MS Office Excel Help and How to - Wrap text in a cell](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/wrap-text-in-a-cell-HP005199835.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy.

1. Highlight all the rows you want to increase the size before &/or after the text.
2. Click on "Home" on toolbar.
3. Below "Alignment Tab and to left of the "abc" button, you will see three icon boxes each one having three lines. They will vertically align your text top, centre, or bottom. To increase the space between the text and the top and bottom of its cell, click the middle (centre) box.
4. Then go to extreme right and click on "Format" and click on "Row Height.
5. Increase row height to the extra size you want. You are done. To increase only the space between text and top line, click on the icon to the immediate left of the "abc" button.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the question content doesn't reflect the title very correctly.

If you need a permanent [**line break**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), i.e. moving the `aaaaddd` to a new line, then do like Mehper C. Palavuzlar's answer

> - Double-click the cell in which you want to insert a line break
> - Click the location where you want to break the line.
> - Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to insert the line break.
>
> [Insert a line break in a cell](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-line-break-in-a-cell-A918E875-625E-4510-86D7-9F5873FE21C7)

["Word wrap"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap) means printing the word on a new line when there's not enough space, so to wrap it just resize the column to make it narrower, or add new text before that word

If you need to add **spaces** at the beginning of the cell then the easiest way is adding an ' (apostrophe) before. This also applies if you need to begin the cell will =, + or -, or format any number/data type as string

For example:

```
  Input: '    abc123
Display: "    abc123"
  Input: '0001234
Display: 0001234
  Input: '=A1/B5
Display: "=A1/B5"
  Input: '-B2-8
Display: "-B2-8"
```

If you need to add spaces in the middle or at the end of the string then this may not be a real question

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question six years later and found [Mehper's accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/217541/512016) useful, but by chance I discovered an additional feature concerning <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, that might be useful for others. As it turns out, with Wrap Text, Excel does not allow initial whitespace on new lines. If you need whitespace (for example to align text in complex forms), you can achieve this also with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, as shown in these two screenshots:

[image: Wrap Text]

In the next screenshot <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is performed after the word *perspiciatis*:
[image: ALT + ENTER]